# Insert multiple rows into the database using Entity Framework in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm having an algorithm which creates a huge set of data in lists which have to be inserted into a database table. I can just put a loop through the entity save changes but is there a bit better way than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AddRange` for insert multiple rows into table like this:

```cs
var list=new List<YourModel>();

await dbContext.YouModels.AddRangeAsync(list);

await dbContext.SaveChangeAsync();
```

That works fine but it's recommended to use an extension for EF called `EFCore.BulkExtensions` with high performance like this:

```cs
var list=new List<YourModel>();
await dbContext.BulkInsertAsync(entities);
```